# How to include pandas columns into a function

Tags: python, pandas, function

I am trying to use pandas columns inside a function.

Function :

```
from iapws import IAPWS97
steam = IAPWS97(P=10,T=803.15)
print(steam.h)

Answer - 3451.665247242002.
```

Pandas dataframe:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({"Pressure": [78,82,77,69],
          "Temperature":[750,770,690,710],
        })
```

I want to use "Pressure" and "Temperature" column in the function. For example P=test["Pressure"].

I tried below code.

```
x = test["Pressure"]
y= test["Temperature"]

def enthalpy(x,y):
    return IAPWS97(P=x,T=y)

steam.h= enthalpy(x,y)
```

Value error - The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Can someone please explain how I can do this?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Probably your function IAPWS97 is not implemented for a series.

Comment: Use apply with custom functions: `test[['Pressure','Temperature']].apply(lambda x: IAPWS97(*x),axis=1)` or `test[['Pressure','Temperature']].apply(lambda x: IAPWS97(*x).h,axis=1)` ?

Comment: Yes I am also having doubt that It will support single number. Should I use loop or iterate then?

Comment: Yes you have to iterate over the series and call the function for each pair. Use the solution suggested by @anky.

Comment: @ anky.   I have used above function but getting TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Comment: Try `test[['Pressure','Temperature']].apply(lambda x: IAPWS97(P=x['Pressure'],T=x['Temperature']).h,axis=1)`

Comment: @anky this one works very well. Thanks a lot.